# SignalR basic sample issues

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

I'm trying to follow the SignalR [quickstart](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/QuickStart-Hubs) sample, but I can't get it to work.

Firstly I'm not quite sure where to place the chat.cs hub file in a MVC project - I have tried a few places, but suspect this is where I'm going wrong. It's currently sitting in a folder called signalr in the project root.

The javascript error I'm getting is as follows:

```
GET http://localhost:50109/signalr/hubs 404 (Not Found)
```

I added the signalr nuget package, so I think I should have everything I need!

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, found the following in the [FAQ](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Faq)

> Why does signalr/hubs return 404 or Why do I get 'myhub' is undefined?
>
> First, make sure you have a call to MapHubs() in Global.asax
>
> RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();

I also had to remove the following from my global.asax:

```
BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
```

Guess I need to spend some time re-jigging my bundles so to say.

Comment: Yes because my bundles are fine. If you have a bundle that starts with singalr that might be the issue.